# Is there a way to "not plot" points where the data is NaN?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

If I have two arrays of data X and Y I can easily plot it using matlotlib.

Say I have x=[0,1,2,3,4,5] and y= [3,6,2,6,3,7]

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot1]

In the problem I am working, new data comes each time, so X is increasing each time and I get new Y data. Well, I replot and problem solved.

The difficulty and the background of this question is that sometimes the data in Y is a NaN. The existence of NaN is not a problem, that is how the data is

My question is if there is a simple way for matplotlib to ignore these data *and * not plotting a line covering the wholes

For example if Y=[3,6,2,NaN,3,7] something like

[image: plot2]

but in the same color

I suppose I could programmatically break down the array in arrays of only valid values, but I wonder if matplotlib (or other plot library-plotly perhaps?) supports something like this

Comment: Use `np.nan` instead of `NaN` and it will create what you are expecting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib list not showing 0 or Nan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503395/matplotlib-list-not-showing-0-or-nans)

Comment: @Equinox yes, although my question has the things that were asked of the other question as lacking (an example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.nan` or `math.nan` values:

```py
from math import nan
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(6)
y = [3, 6, 2, nan, 3, 7]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can first filter de x and y in a easy way,

```py
mask = np.isnan(y) ^ True
x = x[mask]
y = y[mask]
```

Doing this you remove the from x and y the positions where y is nan.
The first line see where y is nan, and applies a xor operation for get the where y is not nan. Then you use this mask for get x and the y where y is not nan, then you can plot a line that not breaks.